# In numpy how would be convert values internally

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to `numpy` library.
How values are converted to get below output and internally how the values are changed?

```
 >>> np.convolve([1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0.5])

     o/p: array([ 0. ,  1. ,  2.5,  4. ,  1.5])
```

Comment: Isn't that explained in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html)?

Comment: i saw the documentation. but my question is how it would be the output.

Answer (score 0):

`np.convolve(a, v, mode='full')` function just pushes the first array `a` sliding on the second array `v` step by step from left to right. On every step, we just calculate `v[i]*a` and get `v[i]a[0], v[i]a[1], ..., v[i]a[n]`. We get `len(v)` arrays/lists, adding them together.

The result of `np.convolve([1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0.5])` is calculated as following:
step 1:

```
  1,  2,  3    
          0,  1, 0.5  
a=0,  0,  0,
```

step two:

```
      1,  2,  3 
          0,  1, 0.5  
b=0,  1,  2,  3,
```

step three:

```
           1,  2,   3 
           0,  1, 0.5  
c=0,  0, 0.5,  1, 1.5
```

finally, adding `a`, `b`, and `c`:

```
  0,  0,   0,  
+ 0,  1,   2,  3,   
+ 0,  0, 0.5,  1, 1.5
  -------------------
= 0,  1, 2.5,  4, 1.5
```

Comment: in step 1: how did you calculate. and  in  v[i] , i  means .

Comment: can you explain this one deeply. please

Comment: In step 1, we got [0, 0, 0] by v[0].*a = 0.*[1, 2, 3], i.e. [0*1, 0*2, 0*3];   
In step 2, [1, 2, 3] = v[1].*a = 1.*[1, 2, 3] = [1, 2, 3];   
In step 3, [0.5, 1, 1.5] = v[2].*a = 0.5.*[1, 2, 3] = [0.5, 1, 1.5];